# Why others can't see my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

I have my site up and running on ubuntu 14.10 in VMware Player and got the URL(http://127.0.0.1/wordpress) .But when other people try to see my site and type the URL (http://127.0.0.1/wordpress) ,they got the message"DEFAULT WEB SITE" and the error summary is "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found".

What can I do to make the site visible to others?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your localhost. its not a real IP. so you should host this site in any shared server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address (one of them, to be technically correct). It's called that because traffic "loops back" to the current (client) machine.

It's *not* the IP address of your machine as seen by the net at large.

So what you have to do is find out:

1/ *Is* your machine (virtual machine) accessible to the net at large?

2/ If so, what is its *actual* IP address or DNS name?

If you've just put together a Wordpress site locally on you box connected to an ISP, you may find you can't easily run a server. It will depend on the ISP.

That's why web hosting companies like BlueHost, Site5 or GreenGeeks exist.

They provide all the infrastructure for you, virtual machine, IP addresses, DNS names, easy WP and plug-in installs, backups and so on.

By doing that, you can then concentrate on the *content,* which is probably why you chose Wordpress in the first place, yes?, rather than having to write your own HTML :-)